# What does expectation of $\varepsilon_{c,t}$ conditional on $_c$ mean?

Tags: mathematical-economics

From a discussion, I [recieve a mathematic answer](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/45333/35009), I understand until one point

> This decomposition can always be made by setting **$\delta_c$ to be the
> expectation of $\varepsilon_{c,t}$ conditional on $c$** and $\gamma_t$
> to be the expectation of $\varepsilon_{c,t}$ conditional on $t$

Can I ask what does this mean when saying "**$\delta_c$ to be the
expectation of $\varepsilon_{c,t}$ conditional on $c$**"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional expectation just means expectation conditional on some additional variable. I assume you already understand that expected value is is the average value or mean of a random variable and that the observed data can be viewed as the values of a collection of independent identically distributed random variables. Consequently, sample mean is defined as the expectation of the data with respect to the empirical distribution for the observed data so for a random sample $E[x]=\mu_x$.

Conditional expectation just means we are conditioning the expectation on some other set of variables. For example, suppose that at a university expected grade (X) of a sample of students is 8 (I am using Dutch grading system that is on scale 1-10), then let us suppose that expected grade of females in that sample is 9 and expected grade of males in that sample is 7. If we denote gender as a dummy where $D=1$ signifies females and $D=0$ signifies males, then in this case:

*unconditional expected grade is* $E[X]=8$

*conditional expected grade, conditional on being female is* $E[X|D=1]=9$

*conditional expected grade, conditional on being male is* $E[X|D=0]=7$

Thus saying that "*$δ_c$ to be the expectation of $ε_{c,t}$ conditional on $c$*" is just saying that $\delta_c$ is the expected value $\varepsilon$ conditional on what values $c$ take. For example, if $c$ is number of children you have $\delta_c$ would be expected value $\varepsilon$ given the number of children you happen to have rather than an expectation for anyone with any number of children.

Comment: I think this part ("Thus saying that "*$δ_c$ to be the expectation of $ε_{c,t}$ conditional on $c$*" is just saying that $\delta_c$ is the expected value **$\epsilon$** conditional on what values $c$ take") should be ("Thus saying that "*$δ_c$ to be the expectation of $ε_{c,t}$ conditional on $c$*" is just saying that $\delta_c$ is the expected value  of **$ε_{c,t}$** conditional on what values $c$ take"). I mean $ε_{c,t}$ rather than $\epsilon$

Comment: @Knowledge-chaser yes I omitted subscripts for brevity sake but by $\epsilon$ I meant $\epsilon_{c,t}$

Comment: @Knowledge-chaser oh I noticed I was using epsilon instead of varepsilon I will edit that probably that was bit confusing

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I mean, thank you , 1muflon1